# When my audio system is plugged into a socket, it makes a buzzing noise. Why?

Tags: audio, cable, speakers, noise

people of the Superuser community,

So recently I have acquired [Edifier M1360](https://www.edifier.com/int/en/speakers/m1360-2.1-computer) 2.1 speakers, and when I plugged them in my computer I have noticed that when they are turned on they make a buzzing noise which isn't particularly loud but still is much louder than my entire PC (which I built with intent to make as quiet as possible). At first I thought that this is due something akin to ground loop, but even when I unplug everything from the Edifier subwoofer and just plug it into any outlet in my house by itself without anything attached to it the buzzing noise persists!

What is the cause of this issue? Would it be possible in any way to salvage my speakers and make them entirely quiet, or should I just throw them in the trash bin? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your diagnostics so far are good, confirming the issue is not a ground loop.

Put a piece of wire or foil across the speaker input plug to confirm the cable is not picking up AC hum. If the hum is greatly reduced, replace the plug and wire.

If the hum persists, it's likely a power supply issue. If the power supply is not running hot, then likely the hum is due to failing filter capacitors. If you're technically capable, replace the power supply filter capacitors, or just parallel them with a *large* electrolytic (e.g. 20,000 µFd or larger, with voltage rating the same or higher than the existing caps).